# Android Studio RemoteView: Set Background Color of An ImageButton with a Drawable Resource

Tags: android-studio

I'm making a widget on Android Studio.

**I have a button with a custom shape:**

```html
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="15.5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_box_shape"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_rounded"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="2.75dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
```

**The Shape:**

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
    <corners android:radius="4.5dp" />
</shape>
```

I'd like to use the shape while also setting any color of my choosing.

How can I do that using RemoteViews?

Thank you!